# I am getting auto complete feature only on first row of jquery table?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a sales invoice where I want to dynamically generate row items.
I want an auto complete feature for product codes which fills in the product name.

Product code is generated in purchase invoice.

The issue is that only the first row of the dynamic table is working.

My code is below :

```
<?php   $query ="select product_code_sku,product_name from pur_line_item pli inner join product_code pc on pli.p_line_item_id = pc.p_line_item_id ";
 $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
 $given_themes = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     //array_push($given_themes, $row);
     $given_themes[] = $row;

 }
 $toJSON = array();
foreach($given_themes as $num => $val){
    $toJSON[$num]['label'] = $val['product_code_sku'];
    $toJSON[$num]['value'] = $val['product_name'];
}
$array_final = json_encode($toJSON);
$array_final = preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":/','$1:',$array_final);
//print_r($array_final);
//echo json_encode($toJSON);
 //echo implode(',',$given_themes);
//print_r($given_themes);
// $gt = json_encode($given_themes);
// print_r($gt);
 ?>

<script>
       function complete(){
   // $(document).ready(function(){       
//        alert('start');
$(function(){

//alert('start');

var availableTags =  <?php echo $array_final;?>;

//alert(availableTags);
                $( "#product_code_sku" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: availableTags,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
         // alert(ui.item.product_code_sku);
        $( "#product_code_sku" ).val( ui.item.label);
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {

        $( "#product_code_sku" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#product_name" ).val( ui.item.value);

       // $( "#product_name" ).html( ui.item.product_name );
        //$( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon ); 
        return false;
      }

    })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
       .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.value + "</a>" )
     .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });

//});

}
</script>
```

Comment: i found the cause for this. Actually the complete() function is getting fired too many times as product code sku field  has 10 characters length. Can you tell me why $(document).ready handler is not working with this code? or can we use this function with any other event handler? Please suggest

Comment: can anybody tell me which jquery files to include for autocomplete functionality? Please also specify the order in which files should be included...